# activerecord relationship, has_one vs additional column in existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-design

I have a Customer model which is working fine. Now i got a new requirement. A customer should have one driving licence. Implementation of Licence consists two things -

1. Licence should have two images ( which customer will upload )
2. Licence should have a status ( 'approved', 'pending', 'rejected' etc set by admin )

Now, my doubt is with has_one relation vs additional columns in the customers table. There are two ways to implement it

1. I create a `Licence` model with attributes - `front_image`, `back_image`, `status` and create a `has_one` `belongs_to` relationship between Licence and Customer.
2. I create additional column, `licence_status`, `licence_front_image`, `licence_back_image` to `Customer` model itself.

Which is a better way to do it ?

Comment: If there is a chance in future you will be adding some more columns to the License model, then go with **1**, otherwise **2** is good to go..

Comment: According to me `1` is better as Licence is different entity and may need more columns in future. Better to create Licence as different model with `customer_id` in licence table..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, one-to-one relationships are fairly easy to understand, but hard to see when to use one.

An example would be an app that optionally lets a user connect their `Facebook` and `Twitter` accounts.

[image]

In this case, for a particular user, the `facebook_account_id` and the `twitter_account_id` can be `NULL`, which would mean that the user hasn't connected their Twitter and/or Facebook accounts. ALso, the `facebook_accounts` and `twitter_accounts` tables don't reference the `users` table at all.

Of course, you could move all the fields in the `facebook_accounts` table directly into the `user` table.
This is true of any one-to-one relationship, which is why it's hard to see when to use one.

The rule of thumb I follow is this: if you have a logical grouping of fields which can all optionally be `NULL`,
it's a good idea to split those fields out into a separate table in a one-to-one relationship.

In your case, it looks like the `License` model is indeed a logical grouping of fields which could optionally be `NULL`. Hence, go with approach `1`. Also, as mentioned in the comments, if there might be a chance that in the future you'd like to expand the `License` model, it would make more sense to go with the `1`